# VBA Macros How to put in date order then numerical order?

Tags: vba, excel

Just as the title says, how can I put an excel sheet in date order, then numerical order? I know how to do these things separately, but the problem is, is that I need it to stay in date order and THEN be in numerical order. Once I put it in numerical order, the dates become mixed up again. The Date is in Column A while the data is in Column B.

Comment: Do you have the code you have tried so far? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=.Columns(2), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlyes
end with
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Sort option from the Data menu

Comment: Haha I didnt know it was that easy. Thought it would be some crazy VBA code.